# How to use css selector to select sibling of parents div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to select the label whenever the input field is valid or invalid. How do I achieve this?

```
<div class="amplify-flex" style="flex-direction: column;">
   <fieldset class="amplify-flex" style="flex-direction: column;">
      <span class="amplify-visually-hidden">
         <legend>Sign in</legend>
      </span>
      <div class="amplify-flex amplify-field amplify-textfield">
         <label class="amplify-label" for="amplify-id-:r4:">Email</label>
         <div class="amplify-flex amplify-field-group amplify-field-group--horizontal" data-orientation="horizontal">
            <div class="amplify-field-group__field-wrapper amplify-field-group__field-wrapper--horizontal" data-orientation="horizontal"><input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="username" class="amplify-input amplify-field-group__control" id="amplify-id-:r4:" required="" type="text" name="username"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: CSS does not have a parent selector; you will have to use `:has()` here (which still has no support in Firefox, unless explicitly enabled by the user.)

Comment: That would be okay, but I already tried it with has, but can't get it running

Comment: Show what you tried, instead of just telling us how you failed.

Comment: So my idea was to work up the DOM by starting with selecting the .amplify-input class and using :has on it, but there are no nodes available when I use document.querySelector(".amplify-input:has(*)")

Comment: No, you need to start with `.amplify-label`, _that_ is the element you want to target. And that `:has()` to have a following `div` sibling, that contains an input field in a specific state. Although I am not exactly sure what sense your condition _"whenever the input field is valid or invalid"_ is supposed to make - what _else_ could it be?

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it. Shouldn't '''document.querySelector(".amplify-label:has(*)")''' return me at least one node instead of just null? Input field only needs to be valid, my bad.

Comment: `*` is the universal selector that matches elements of any type. `.amplify-label:has(*)` would be looking for an `.amplify-label` element, that _contains_ any other element. Your label does _not_ contain any elements, it has text content only.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a label that has a following sibling, so that would start something like `.amplify-label:has(+ div)`, using the next-sibling combinator. (Or the general sibling combinator, `~`, if there were other nodes between the label and the target div.) And then you need to continue that selector with the part that looks for your input field. `:has(+ div input[aria-invalid=false])`

Comment: I guess '''.amplify-field:has(input:valid) label''' does the job equally good, right?

Comment: Yes, that's just approaching the whole thing from a different "staring point" - and perhaps a bit easier, than having to make sure the sibling relationship is matched correctly.

Comment: Alright, cool. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
.amplify-field:has(input:valid) label
```

Finds all classes (.amplify-field) that have a valid input field AND that have a label as a child

Thanks to @CBroe!